# How to apply anchor links so when scrolled, some space is left on the top?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hash, anchor

I have this example page with three anchor links on it. The links work fine, and after clicking the anchor link, I managed to control how much scrolling happens.

The problem is, on the 1st click the anchor links work fine, but on the second click on a row, the effect wont apply anymore. Any help?

Here is my code:

```js
// SCROLL //

function offsetAnchor() {
  
    if(location.hash.length !== 0) {
        window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY -200);
    }
}

// window.addEventListener("hashchange", offsetAnchor);

window.setTimeout(offsetAnchor, 0); 


// FIRST BUTTON

var firstcontent = document.getElementById("first-content");
var buttonfirst = document.getElementById("firstbtn");

buttonfirst.onclick = function(){

if(firstcontent.className == "openfirst"){
  //show the blue box
  firstcontent.className = "";
  buttonfirst.innerHTML = "Open";
} else {
  // hide the box
  firstcontent.className = "openfirst";
  buttonfirst.innerHTML = "Hide";
}
}

// SECOND BUTTON

var secondcontent = document.getElementById("second-content");
var buttonsecond = document.getElementById("secondbtn");

buttonsecond.onclick = function(){

if(secondcontent.className == "opensecond"){
  //show the blue box
  secondcontent.className = "";
  buttonsecond.innerHTML = "Open";
} else {
  // hide the box
  secondcontent.className = "opensecond";
  buttonsecond.innerHTML = "Hide";
}
}

// THIRD BUTTON

var thirdcontent = document.getElementById("third-content");
var buttonthird = document.getElementById("thirdbtn");

buttonthird.onclick = function(){

if(thirdcontent.className == "openthird"){
  //show the blue box
  thirdcontent.className = "";
  buttonthird.innerHTML = "Open";
} else {
  // hide the box
  thirdcontent.className = "openthird";
  buttonthird.innerHTML = "Hide";
}
}
```

```css
#html:scroll {
  margin-top: 100px;
  position: fixed;
}

/* html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
} */

/* FONTS */

#first-content h2, #second-content h2, #third-content h2 {
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#first-content h3, #second-content h3, #third-content h3 {
  margin: 10px;
}

#first-content p, #second-content p, #third-content p {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-transform: none;
}

/* LOGO CONTAINER */

.logo-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  display: flex;
  height: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo-container h2 {
  font-weight: 900;
}

/* MAIN CONTENT */

.main-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 240px;
  background-color: #ff8800;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.main-content h1 {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}


/* FIRST CONTAINER */

.main-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #c1e8ff;
  padding: 0px 0px 50px 0px;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 550px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

/* BUTTONS */

.buttons {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#firstbtn, #secondbtn, #thirdbtn {
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  min-width: 150px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#firstbtn, #secondbtn, #thirdbtn {
 background-color: #fff;
}

/* BOXES */

.boxes {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* BOX CONTENT FIRST */

#first-content, #second-content, #third-content {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  /* visibility: hidden; */
  display: none;
}

#first-content.openfirst, #second-content.opensecond, #third-content.openthird {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
  /* visibility: visible; */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* justify-content: space-around; */
  /* align-items: center; */
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-animation-name: fadein;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: fadein;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}

/* FONTS */
```

```html
<body>
  
<head>
    <script src="myjs.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="website.css">
</head>
  
<!-- FIRST CONTAINER -->  
<div class="main-container">
  
  <div class="logo-container">
    <h2>TEXT</h2>
  </div>
  
  <div class="main-content">
    <h1>Some text</h1>
  </div>
  
<div class="buttons">
<a href="#first-content" id="firstbtn">Open</a>
</div>
<div class="boxes">
<div id="first-content">
  <h2>SAMPLE 1</h2>
  <h3>PUT SOME SAMPLE HERE</h3>
  <p>Put some text here</p>
  <h3>PUT SOME SAMPLE HERE</h3>
  <p>Put some text here</p>
  <h2>SAMPLE 2</h2>
  <h3>PUT SOME SAMPLE HERE</h3>
  <p>Put some text here</p>
  <h3>PUT SOME SAMPLE HERE</h3>
  <p>Put some text here</p>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- SECOND CONTAINER -->
<div class="buttons">
<a href="#second-content" id="secondbtn">Open</a>
</div>
<div class="boxes">
<div id="second-content">
  <h2>SAMPLE 1</h2>
  <h3>PUT SOME SAMPLE HERE</h3>
  <p>Put some text here</p>
  </div>
</div>
  
<!-- THIRD CONTAINER -->
<div class="buttons">
<a href="#third-content" id="thirdbtn">Open</a>
</div>
<div class="boxes">
<div id="third-content">
  <h2>SAMPLE 1</h2>
  <h3>PUT SOME SAMPLE HERE</h3>
  <p>Put some text here</p>
  </div>
</div>
  
</div>
  
  
  
</body>
```

Comment: What exactly about this is not working? In the code snippet you have shown, I can click those anchor-buttons multiple times, and they seem to open the associated content just fine …?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The problem is, when you click the first "open" button, you can see, the page scrolls down just enough to keep that button still visible above the content it just opened. That is how I want it to be. The problem occurs when you click the button again to close the content, and then click it again to open the content. On the second/third click it scrolls the content to the top of the page and you cannot see the button above the same way you did on the first click.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because your page is too small. It works fine on the other two examples too, but the content to show isnt there.

To understand what I mean try setting the `main-content` class from 100% height to something like 2000px. Now there is more content to show and the button clicks will work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The problem is, when you click the first "open" button, you can see, the page scrolls down just enough to keep that button still visible above the content it just opened. That is how I want it to be. The problem occurs when you click the button again to close the content, and then click it again to open the content. On the second/third click it scrolls the content to the top of the page and you cannot see the button above the same way you did on the first click.